# Numerical algorithm to solve quadratic eigenvalue problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Given the equation $$-4 \left(a^2+a (n-1) (2 t^2-1)\right) \left(\sum _{i=0}^n \alpha_i t^{2 i}\right)^2 \\
+\frac12 \left(\sum _{i=0}^n \alpha_i t^{2 i}\right) \left(t \left(8 a (t^2-1)+1\right) \sum _{i=0}^n 2 i \alpha_i t^{2 i-1}+(t^2-1) \sum _{i=0}^n 2 i (2 i-1) \alpha_i t^{2 i-2}\right) \\
-\frac14(t^2-1) \left(\sum _{i=0}^n 2 i \alpha_i t^{2 i-1}\right)^2=4C\left(\sum _{i=0}^n \alpha_i t^{2 i}\right)^2,$$

where $t \in[-1,1]$, $a$ being a fixed in $\mathbb{R}$ and $C,\alpha_0,...,\alpha_n$ unknown. I am looking for a way to numerically compute the unknown variables. In principle, this is very similar to an eigenvalue problem, where $C$ is the eigenvalue. The problem is that the equation is not linear in the $\alpha_i$. What would be the best way to solve this equation numerically?

Comment: I guess that it's gonna be very complex, but you could take a look at the Limited-memory BFGS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS

Comment: Assign a set of values to the $\alpha_i$, you have a linear equation for $C$. This is just not determining anything.

Comment: @vonbrand I don't understand your comment.